# Options Menu not appearing in API level 15

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-optionsmenu

My manifest reads

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
```

I have created options menu with two items using the following methods

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
Log.d(TAG,"onCreateOptionsMenu");
MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu1, menu);}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)...
```

My menu1 xml is as follows

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:id="@+id/eh_view" android:title="Edit Catagories"></item>
<item android:id="@+id/pin_project" android:title="Pin Project"></item>
```

When I run the app on a API level 9 (Gingerbread the menu works perfectly. However, when I run the same app on API level 15 the menu doesn't appear. I was expecting an action bar to appear on the cell phone with API level 15. Am I missing some code?

Comment: please share your onCreateOptionsMenu() code...

Comment: added the code and the xml for menu1.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Android documentation for the ActionBar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html). Make sure you have a theme in your `AndroidManifest.xml` that is `Holo` (or a decendent like `Holo.Light`). Not all themes support ActionBars.